# Which adapters serve video out from a first generation MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, displayport, video-adapter

It is not a mini DisplayPort. I tried that and it doesn't fit.

As far as I can tell, Apple don't make them any more.

Comment: Is it mini-DVI?

Comment: Hardware shopping topics are off topic on the main site - you could try in [chat] perhaps.

Comment: Too bad. It must be a common problem amongst owners of the first generation MacBook Air, and the answer is probably true for quite long. I can see you point in principle, but it would really solve a very real problem for Apple users.

Comment: @segiddins I'm fairly new to Mac. It might be a mini DVI. I looked at Wikipedia but couldn't really make head or tail of it.

Comment: The first generation MacBook Airs were Micro-DVI.

Comment: ah I was close!, kyle why not add that as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first generation MacBook Airs were Micro-DVI

(According to Kyle Cronin.)